# Two confusions about transform stream part of node.js documentation around pre-ES6 style

Tags: node.js, transform-stream

Here is the [doc](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v17.x/api/stream.html#new-streamtransformoptions) I am confused with.

> When using pre-ES6 style constructors

```
const { Transform } = require('stream');
const util = require('util');

function MyTransform(options) {
  if (!(this instanceof MyTransform))
    return new MyTransform(options);
  Transform.call(this, options);
}
util.inherits(MyTransform, Transform);
```

1. Why do we need to check `this instanceof MyTransform`? As far as I know, as long as we invoke `new MyTransform()`, evaluation of `this instanceof MyTransfrom` will always return `true`. Maybe using `MyTransform()` to create a `Transform` instance can be found in many code bases? This is the only reason I could guess.
2. What is the purpose of `util.inherits(MyTransform, Transform);` ? Just to ensure that `new MyTransform() instanceof Transform` returns `true`?

Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `MyTransform` is just a function like any other function. There's nothing special about it, and so calling it *as* a function (without `new`) will work perfectly fine. So what should happen in that case? According to this code: fall through to a constructor call and returning the resulting instance object.
2. As per [the documentation for that function](https://nodejs.org/dist./v8.14.1/docs/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) it enforces prototype inheritance, because again, you wrote `MyTransform` as just a plain function: while you can use `new` with any function, you didn't write any of the code necessary for proper prototype inheritance so using `new` will give you a completely useless object. That means either you add the code necessary to set set up prototype inheritance yourself, or you ask a utility function to do that for you.

Comment: From my perspective, I will assume that `MyTransform` is a constructor and should be invoked with `new` because the capitalized initial character `M`. I am confused with `util.inherits(MyTransform, Transform)` because I will get what I need no matter how I invoke the function - `MyTransform()` or `new MyTransform()`. In the end, `Transform.call(this, options)` will do the job. So I will not say it will give a completely useless object. But yes, it is completely without prototype inheritance. Just wondered does `util.inherits(MyTransform, Transform)` do anything else beyond the inheritance?

Comment: It isn't: as per the JS spec _what you wrote is a function_ and the only thing that makes it a constructor is the use of `new`, and because JS lets you call any function as a function, the code you're asking about in (1) is there _because_ it can be called without `new`, in which case you want to return a new instance anyway. The JS spec says you should be able to call a function as a function, so unless you're using `class` syntax, a function that can be used as constructor should always have a check to see how it's getting invoked. As for (2): you have the link to the official docs =)

Comment: Not only we have JS spec to reference but also naming conventions to follow. :)

Comment: Not really, no? The answer to _your question_, namely "why is this code here", has a JS spec answer: it's there because functions are functions. Conventions are nice, but they don't _prevent_ people from calling a function that starts with a capital letter as a function. In fact, there are some web APIs with "capital first letter" functions that throw warnings/errors if you try to call them with `new`, and some that throw warnings/errors if you _don't_ call them with `new`. You asked why we need the instanceof check: this answer explains why.

Comment: So always checking how a function being invoked is a best practice then? The implementation of a function can also go the way to throw a warning/error if it is not called with `new` just like the web APIs you've mentioned. At least this can force a constant usage for a specific function which is single purpose. And yes, my question is answered. Just would like to discuss it further. Thank you!

Comment: If you write code that you intend for others to work with in _any_ way, always making sure your code accounts for all valid code paths so that it does the _objectively_ right thing even if it runs in a _subjectively_ wrong way is good software engineering.